# Filter ngrepeat based on multi search inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have an array of objects.  I am trying to setup a way to filter by each column from the user input.

each col has a input dropdown where you can select a value, with the idea that you would be able to select a different filter per column.

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
```

row 1
row 2 
row 3
row 4 
.
.

Currently, i have created a function, and I am passing it all the filter selections from the user.   Thus doing something like this:

> Blockquote

Where filterArray is all 8 of the different filters.

Then I am checking to see if that filter value selected for the column equals the column value for the row.

With 8 different options, this turns into a lot of if statements permutations.   Is that they only way to do this?

Comment: please include some code

Comment: The key concept i didn't realize is that you can just chain each filter together.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding a solution .   I didn't realize that you can add multi filters chained together.